# Is there anything like spring-hateoas' AnnotationMappingDiscoverer for RESTEasy?

Tags: java, resteasy, spring-hateoas

When using Spring's HATEOAS support, I really like the [`AnnotationMappingDiscoverer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/api/org/springframework/hateoas/core/AnnotationMappingDiscoverer.html) which helps avoid hard-coding REST resource paths in tests. With it, I can do things like

```
discoverer = new AnnotationMappingDiscoverer(RequestMapping.class);
Method method = MyController.class.getMethod("myResourceMethod", params);
String path = discoverer.getMapping(method);
```

And then use that `path` as the resource path in tests. Much better than hard-coding paths in tests that have to be kept in sync with the controller class and method annotations.

Is there anything similar for RESTEasy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [UriBuilder](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-rev-a/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html):

Assuming following class:

```
@Path("persons")
public class PersonResource {

    @Path("/{id}")
    public Response get(@PathParam("id") String id) {
      //
    }

}
```

You would get the path like this:

```
URI path = UriBuilder.fromResource(PersonResource.class)
                     .path(PersonResource.class, "get")
                     .build("4711");
// path = /persons/4711
```